# query to show Active employees for a given time frame

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am a little new to building this but have come a long way.

I have built a db using Access 2007. I have a table that shows the employees info:

```
Lname  
Fname  
Status  
HireDate  
TermDate
```

(Status: they are either inactive (potential Hires), Active or Terminated)

I can run a query that will show me all the employees by hire date or run one to show term dates.

We would like to have a query that will give us a count of how many drivers are still there within a given month.

Say Joe Smith was hired on 01/01/2008 and was terminated on 05/15/2011. If I ran a report in 2011 on May 31st how would I need to build the query to show this employee as being there in the month of May?

I have used `>=Date()` and others. I could use `between #05/01/2011# and #06/01/2011#` in the criteria under `TermDate` but if there is not a date there, nothing shows up. I have even dropped down a line and added "Null" and still nothing or I get all the employees that are still there and the ones that was terminated before the dates. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about the logic for the filter criteria on this one.  I think your goal is to identify all drivers who were on staff during any part of May 2011.  My best guess is you need at least 2 conditions to identify them.

- `HireDate` prior to June 1, 2011
- `TermDate` either Null or >= May 1, 2011

If those conditions are sufficient, the SQL could be fairly easy.

```sql
SELECT e.Lname, e.Fname
FROM employees_info AS e
WHERE
    e.HireDate < #2011-6-1#
    AND
    (
        e.TermDate Is Null
        OR
        e.TermDate >= #2011-5-1#
    );
```

It sounds like you're building the query in Design View ... which is a good and helpful feature.  However, it's difficult to describe how to build that query in Design View.  So I suggest you create a new query, switch to SQL View and paste in that SQL text.  Replace `employees_info` with your actual table name, and fix any field names I misspelled.

If that query runs without error, you can flip back and forth between Design and SQL view, make a change in one, and examine how it is represented in the other view.

The SQL doesn't have to be formatted the way I wrote it. I chose that way in hopes it would make the `WHERE` logic clear.  And if you make changes to the query from Design View, Access will reformat the SQL as it sees fit.  However, the formatting change should not break the query.

I used *yyyy-m-d* format for the literal date values.  That format avoids any possible confusion over which parts represent day and month, such as whether `#05-01-2011#` is intended to represent May 1st or Jan 5th.  However, when you alter the query, Access may change them to *mm-dd-yyyy* format. (Sometimes its *"helpful"* impulses are annoying.)

I'm puzzled about one point.  It seems you have one record per employee.  If that is so, and an employee can leave for any reason and be re-hired later,  it would be difficult to capture the different employment terms in a single record.  If you're facing that situation, you may need to revise table designs.

If I misinterpreted your data, please show us a brief data sample, and the output you want from the query based on that sample.  Good luck with this.

Comment: that sounds great! I will work on this and get back to you. WE run this query each month so I would have to go in and change the dates each month right?

Comment: For that query, yes.  But you could create a different query where you supply date values as parameters to indicate the start and end range of dates you want the query to evaluate.  That's beyond the scope of what you asked in this question.  When you're ready to tackle something like that, make a new question and please include a brief set of relevant sample data and the output you want based on that sample.

Comment: Actually you may be able to find enough information by searching SO for [tag:ms-access] and parameter query.  Do that before submitting a new question.